# Is there a known pattern for scheduling events programatically?

Tags: calendar, design-patterns, schedule, recurring

Does anyone have a known, solid solution for the scheduling of events (i.e. appointments, meetings, etc) within a system. I'm speaking here of "events" as tasks that need to be done on a one-time or recurring basis and executed based on a schedule. I've found a schedule UI component by DevExpress and it has some reference to using custom objects but I figure someone must have solved this problem nicely already. Thanks in advance everyone for the time and effort.

Byron Crowell

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nice [discussion of scheduling in .NET](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/11/11/Not-invented-here-useful-noneteless.aspx) from Ayende.